# How to intercept a delegate call by using a class

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, action

Basicly, what I want to archive is way to intercept a call to a delegate. I was thinking to define a class that can be used for it. Something like:

```
timer.Elapsed += new MyClass((sender, e)=> { /* do stuff */});
```

How do I define `MyClass` in a generic way?

I could let `Myclass` inherent from `ElapsedEventHandler`, but than it can only be used for this event. I was thinking to let `MyClass` inherent from `Action<object, EventArg>` since you can also write

```
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => { /* do stuff */ }
```

But I did not get that one working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can't create your class that will be delegate, however you can create a delegate from your class.

Consider a class:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Now you connect your class method to the event:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
timer.Elapsed += obj.OnTimerElapsed;
```

You can also disconnect it:

```
timer.Elapsed -= obj.OnTimerElapsed;
```

You should read more about events in C#, like in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Good workaround. A delegate `A` cannot be converted to a delegate `B` - *but* a method group can be converted to a delegate `A` or a delegate `B` as long as their signatures are compatible. +1

Comment: Well this is not a workaround, this is the way it should be done :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't - In C#'s type system there is no relationship between two delegates, even if their signatures match.

For example, `Func<T, bool>` and `Predicate<T>` are unrelated.

---

Also, your assumption that the expression `(sender, e) => { /* do stuff */}` is of type `Action<object, EventArg>` is wrong. Lambda expressions don't have a type, *per se*. They are *converted* to delegates, depending on the context.

That's why you can't assign a lambda expression to a `var` - because the type cannot be inferred - because there is no type.

```
var del = (int i) => i + 1;         //incorrect
Func<int, int> del = i => i + 1;    //correct
CustomDelegate del = i => i + 1;    //correct


delegate int CustomDelegate(int i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright. That's tricky. But I have to say.. it's possible by using the wonderful world of implicit conversions. Try starting like this..

```
// define a new class called EventCall
public class EventCall<T> {
    // this one will be returned to be executed directly after your initialization
    public T Handler { get; private set; }

    public EventCall(T handler) {
        if (handler == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");
        this.Handler = handler;
        // the intercept code can be inserted here..
        // but i can't see any point of doing this..
    }

    // this method will return the handler directly after the initialization
    public static implicit operator T(EventCall<T> c) {
        return this.Handler;
    }
}

// now you can use it like
timer.Elapsed += new EventCall<ElapsedEventHandler>((sender, args) => { /* code to invoke */ });
```

This one works. I've just tested it by myself. But the type-parameter `T` always needs to match the correct event handler type..

What this code does is basically using the `T` parameter to get the type for a new object which is directly passed to the constructor and then (via implicit conversion) immediately returned back. It's kinda overkill.. but whatever. Hope that helped..

Comment: The implicit operator opened some new perspective. But I'm not yet there. I want to intercept the code when the event fires, but use some data that was gathered when the interceptor was created. That I already managed to do with some insights from the other answers. I hope that this answer all parts may come together.

Comment: ok. can you give some more information. maybe I'm just dumb but I'm unable to figure out your exact need..

Comment: Well, if I insert code where you write 
// the intercept code can be inserted here..
// but i can't see any point of doing this..
It will be executed when EventCall is constructed. When the event triggers it still just executes the handler like you got it. It is at that point that I want to do additional stuff.
So, what I would like to do is more like:
return (sender, e) => { DoStuff(); this.Handler(sender, e); }

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but that's simply not really possible the way I answered. There are surley some ways of evil event hooking stuff to spy when exactly the event is fired and which parameters were used for it...

Comment: I don't like evil hooks, so i came to peas with "it can not be done". Although I don't like "it can't be done" either.